# Анимация ImageView перемещение вверх и исчезновение при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: java, android, анимация, animate, android-animation

Вопрос по поводу анимации *Imageview*.

Как сделать так, чтобы по нажатии на кнопку картинка поползла по оси чуть  немного вверх и исчезла?

Answer (score 1):

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {

        imageView.animate().translationYBy(100).alpha(0).setDuration(1000);

    }

}
```